# Using GeoServer API how can I create multiple layers from same datastore?

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

The datastore is a connection to a solr core. I can create this just fine. I find when I create a new layer by posting a new featuretype xml, I am forced to name the file the same name as the data source (solr core). This only allows me to create one layer, with the same name as the solr core.

Is it possible to create multiple layers from the same datastore using the GeoServer API?

Comment: can't you just change the name in the XML file you post - http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/examples/curl.html#uploading-a-shapefile